NEFs not Opening Anywhere
I have 300 or so NEF (Nikon) files that won't open anywhere. I have tried File Explorer, Photoshop, Lightroom, and even quite a few file converters. I don't want to lose all of these photos. Any hints for a fix would be greatly appreciated. I'll see if I can attach one of the files.

Which LR or PS versions did you try.

Newer camera NEF files won't open in older versions of LR and PS. You can use Adobe's DNG Converter program to convert to DNG format.

I am not experienced in this area, but it would seem shocking to me that a camera manufacturer wouldn't provide software to read the files produced by their own cameras. So - have you tried whatever software Nikon themselves make available? After a quick web search, this software seems to be called either Capture NX2 or NX Studio.

I use latest version of NX Studio to transfer JPEG and NEF from my camera (Nikon ZFC MILC) media to my PC and work with these files. What camera/model and when are  your NEF files from? Do you have issue with all NEF files or only few of them?
